# System.NullReferenceException (Radio buttons)

Tags: c#, exception, radio-button

I have two radio buttons and if i put the attribute `IsChecked` in XAML, the program crashes with a System.NullReferenceException. Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

My radio buttons:

```
<RadioButton IsChecked="True" Name="Mint" Checked="Mint_Checked_1"
  Foreground="Red"  FlowDirection="RightToLeft"  VerticalAlignment="Top"
  HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Margin="10,30,10,0" GroupName="Update_When"
  Content="A">
</RadioButton>

<RadioButton IsChecked="False" Name="Changet" Checked="Changet_Checked_1"
  FlowDirection="RightToLeft" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
  Margin="10,53,10,0" GroupName="Update_When" Content="B">
</RadioButton>
```

My event code:

```
private void Mint_Checked_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Mint.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
        Changet.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
    }

    private void Changet_Checked_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Mint.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
        Changet.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code for your checked events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting that exception because you are calling the checked event before the element is initialized, one way to solve this is to move the `IsChecked=True` to a Loaded event:

```
private void MyWindow_Loaded (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Mint.IsChecked = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, I moved the xaml line for the RadioButton that was to be checked to the last line in the sequence as follows:

Original order in XAML file, (This order causes an exception to be thrown)

```
RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton1"
RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton2" // Radio button that is initialized as selected (Is_Checked)
RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton3"
RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton4"
```

NO exception:

```
RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton1"
RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton3"
RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton4"
RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton2" // Radio button that is initialized as selected (checked)
```

I believe this is because when a radio button changes to "Is_checked" (even on initialization) it calls the RadioButton_IsChecked method to which it is bound.

So, during initialization RadioButton1 was initialized to false, then RadioButton2 was initialized to true which called the bound method and RadioButton3 and RadioButton4 were still not initialized and were null which caused the exception.

Note, the above does not change the location of the Radio Buttons on the form.

Also, I have bound all 4 radio buttons to the same method and use if/else if/else if/else to set the form properties I want when a button is checked.